# Server-side rendering with React Router "Browser history needs a DOM"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I've scanned through the internet for two days but I can't get the gist of implementing SSR with react-routes. It took me 5 days to somehow understand all this *without the routes*. But now I'm unable to understand further with using *react-routes*. Here's the necessary details-

**server/server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from '../src/App';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./build')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send('Some error happened');
        }

        const context = {};
        const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                <App />
            </StaticRouter>
        )
        
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${app}</div>`
      )
    );
    });
    
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App launched on ${PORT}`);
});
```

**server/index.js**

```
require('ignore-styles')

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
})

require('./server')
```

**src/App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Link to='/about'>This is Home. Go to About.</Link>} />
        <Route path='/about' component={() => <Link to='/'>This is About. Go to Home.</Link>} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Look at: https://github.com/Lomray-Software/vite-ssr-boost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `BrowserRouter` from the App and put it in your index file.

### index.js

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(
       <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
       </BrowserRouter>, 
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={() => <Link to='/about'>This is Home. Go to About.</Link>} />
        <Route path='/about' component={() => <Link to='/'>This is About. Go to Home.</Link>} />
      </Switch>
  );
}
```

Since `<App />` contains `BrowserRouter` and you're using it in the server. `BrowserRouter` cannot be processed in the server since it requires DOM.

Also, import your `StaticRouter` from `react-router` not `react-router-dom`.

You could check the docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter)

```
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
```

Comment: What's the difference? It still goes through hydrate.

Comment: The `hydrate` function is not run in the server. It runs in the clientside ( browser ).

Comment: Anyways he is using react router dom in his server.js file and I think this is the issue.

Comment: Ohh! I missed that, that's also one of the issue.

Comment: @PrateekThapa Wrapping the `<App />` with `BrowserRouter` solved the issue, without the latter point you mentioned

Comment: Okay. Seems like `react-router-dom` also have a `StaticRouter` exported, I reckon. But the docs says it's `react-router`

Comment: I'm really trying to dive deeper into understanding all this routing with ssr, but the source I encountered `StaticRouter` from also uses `react-router-dom`

Comment: Basically, StaticRouter works on the server and BrowserRouter on the  client. That's it. Since BrowserRouter implicitly takes location from `window.location` in the client, we need to explicitly pass location to the StaticRouter. After that, everything is just the same.

Comment: StaticRouter is missing